# Why is it that all Kuki family members have X scar on their forehead?

Tags: majikoi

In the original Majikoi, only Kuki Hideo and Kuki Ageha was shown. The other members of the Kuki family wasn't shown. In Majikoi S, the rest of the family was shown. Interestingly it is not only Kuki Hideo and Kuki Ageha that has the X scar on their forehead.

My question is, how come that everyone, including the elderly Kuki Marple, Kuki Abone, and the young Kuki Monshiro has that scar too?

Answer (score 1):

In Majikoi S, Kuki Moshiro's route, it was explained that the scar was carved on the Kuki family member forehead when they were baby. Monshiro was an exception in that hers was carved after she was a little bit older. From the way she said it, this is a family tradition of the Kuki family.